# Closed sets under norm topology and strong operator topology

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-algebras

Let $X$ be a Banach space with norm $\|\cdot\|$, and $\mathcal{B}(X)$ the space of bounded operators on $X$. If a sequence $(f_n)_n\subset \mathcal{B}(X)$ converges under the norm topology, $f_n \to f\in\mathcal{B}(X)$, then we also have pointwise-convergence: for all $x\in X$, $\|f_n(x)-f(x)\|\leq \|f_n-f\|_\text{OP}\cdot \|x\|\to 0$. So the sequence also converges under the strong operator topology. The same is true for nets.

If I'm not mistaken, the S.O.T is a coarser (weaker) topology than the norm topology. However, wouldn't the above results imply every norm-closed sets in $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is also S.O.T-closed? Wouldn't that then imply the S.O.T is finer than (at least as fine as) the norm topology? Can anyone tell me what I got wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'wouldn't the above results imply every norm-closed sets in $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is also S.O.T-closed?'. No, it works the other way. If $M$ is S.O.T. closed, $(f_n) \in M$ and $f_n \to f$ in operator norm, then $f_n \to f$ S.O.T which implies $f \in M$. So  S.O.T. closed implies norm closed.

Comment: In general topological spaces, can I understand it the following way? On the same set $S$, if two topologies $\tau_1\subset \tau_2$, then for any subset $A\subset S$, the two closures should satisfy $cl_{\tau_2}(A)\subset cl_{\tau_1}(A)$? Because $cl_{\tau_2}(A)$ is not necessarily closed in $\tau_1$?

Comment: @user760 $cl_{r_2}(A)\subset cl_{r_1}(A)$ is correct.

Comment: But is this property alone enough to conclude $\tau_1\subset \tau_2$? Could it be this property is satisfied, but there's no relation between $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$?

Comment: It is enough. If $A$ is closed in $\tau_1$ then we get $cl_{\tau_2} \subset A$ which implies that $A$ is closed in $\tau_2$ also.  By complementation, every open set in $\tau_1$ is open in $\tau_2$. @user760

Comment: Oh, so for $A$ closed in $\tau_1$, we have $A\subset cl_2(A) \subset A$. I see. Thanks